# Solr Error Parent filter should not be sent when the schema is nested

Tags: solr, nested

This is the my current simple solr doc

`{
    "id": 1,
    "type": "dad",
    "_childDocuments_": [
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Alice"
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "Bob"
        }
    ]
}`

You should be able to use `childFilter` along with the `parentFilter`

**However I keep getting this error: "Parent filter should not be sent when the schema is nested"**

Query:

```
q=type:dad&fl= *,[child parentFilter=type:dad childFilter=name:Alice limit=10]
```

This should then be result but I am getting the error above:

```
"response": {
"numFound": 1,
"start": 0,
"docs": [
    {
        "id": "1",
        "type": ["dad"],
        "_version_": 1603065478506348544,
        "type_str": ["dad"],
        "_childDocuments_": [
            {
                "id": "2",
                "name": ["Alice"],
                "_version_": 1603065478506348544,
                "name_str": ["Alice"]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

}

Comment: What is your solr version?

Comment: See [Getting parent filter should not be sent when the schema is nested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55487611/getting-parent-filter-should-not-be-sent-when-the-schema-is-nested-when-using).

Comment: I am using the latest Solr 8.1.1 @KalpeshBoghara

Comment: I have already tried what is said in the link provided by @MatsLindh but it did not work and I am still getting the same error.